# How can I monitor scroll on a prepend <div> other than overflow:scroll;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to monitor scroll on a prepend `<div>`. I have a `<div>` running at a page. The Scroll of the page is the one which is working. the Prepened `<div>` has a scroll but the the one on the page is working. I am using it to hit ajax on url by calculating the bottom distance. I want to do so on the upper prepended `<div>` any idea how?

Comment: Please add a demo of what you have so far... Also, you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to be more complete with your question,  possibly adding some of the code you've written till now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:auto;` instead of `overflow:scroll;` and also paste your some code or create a fiddle example to be more specific.

Comment: `<div data-role="ajax-data-table" is-scrollable="true" bottom-distance="100"` is what i want my div to react with. Here i am calculating the bottom distance so as to re-hit my API to get more data as the page goes down. i have a container in which i am coding and have a link which opens,
`$( ".inner" ).prepend("<div class='row'style='position: fixed; z-index:1; background-color:#f5f5f5; width:100%; height:85%; overflow:auto;'>"`. the problem i am facing is that i am only receiving the scroll distance of the container and not this prepend <div>
PS:- Sorry ,new to stackoverflow please excuse.

Comment: Request you to please share the link of the page you are working on or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link if you can create.

Comment: `https://jsfiddle.net/dfewdsqy/` not sure if you will be able to understand. PS my first try on fiddle.